# D3 module loading yields Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: d3.js, requirejs, commonjs

I am trying to use d3 as a npm package in a commonJS Module, and load it using require. var d3 = require("d3"). But the require call fails at this line 
 var d3_document = this.document;

Comment: I found this https://github.com/d3/d3-request/issues/10. But I am not sure what the author meant, about Node not knowing about the DOM. In that case how should I be leveraging D3 as npm package ?